# After click open new page and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

after click on element (.more-address) new page is open,  and I want to add class in that new page?

```
<div class="address"><a href="/contacts.html#test" class="more-address">see more</a></div>

 $('.address).on('click', '.more-address'){
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
 $('.list-items').find('.list-item').removeClass('is-active'); 
 $('.list-items').find(href).parent('.list-item').addClass('is-active');
)};
```

Comment: _add class in that new page_.....please clarify this as much as possible.

Comment: Looking at the hyperlink, it simply opens new page with GET request. You can't change new page's content from old page scripts. It's impossible. If you want to manipulate the content of new page, load it via ajax, place on the same page and do corrections. You can use $("#elementid").load("/contacts.html#test") and later add class to the desired elements.

Comment: You may have to do it the script written within "contacts.html" file. On completion of loading file you have do it. That is one of the way.

Comment: You can indeed change the content of a new page from an old page. You pass along some indicator, via the GET url, that tells the new page what to do. Naive example, you'd send http://.../newpage?pagetype=[type1|type2|etc] and so on. The new page grabs the info and feeds it to it's processing scripts. This can make the new page use different calls to get data, completely alter the markup, etc. Note also that in a SPA, you don't necessarily have to navigate to a new page. The old page can put data in local storage and the new page can access it (then delete it)...many ways.

Answer (score 0):

***On the opened page*** you can do this in the document ready block:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var el = window.location.hash;
   $('.list-item.is-active').removeClass('is-active'); 
   $(el).closest('.list-item').addClass('is-active');
});
```